# How to set the current "version number" of migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

I have a bunch of migrations, but due to some weird reason, rails suddenly forgot that it has ran most of these already. Now when I try to run `rake db:migrate`, rails will try to run ALL of the migrations.

How do I set the current "version number" or whatever it's called so that rails knows that "oh I already ran the first 5 migrations, I should start from the 6th one"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `schema_migrations` table stores the numbers for all the migrations that have been run (just the numeric part). If you fill it with all the migration numbers that you think have already run rails shouldn't try to run them again.

Comment: Oh that also explains why rails "forgot" the old migrations. I moved databases recently and accidentally neglected to move over the schema_migrations table. Thanks!